# Binomial coefficient as a summation series proof?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Alright, so I was wondering if the following is a well known identity or if its existence provides any real benefits other than serving as a time-saver when dealing with higher values for combinations.

After screwing around with some basic combinations stuff, I noticed the following:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \begin{pmatrix}n\\2\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

To prove this, I used Gauss' method to simplify the summation, and I wrote n choose 2 in terms of factorials to simplify the right side.

$$ \frac{ (n-1) n } {2} = \frac{ n! } { (2!) (n-2)! } $$

$$ 2!(n-2)!(n-1)(n) = 2n! $$

$$ 2(n-2)!(n-1)(n) = 2n! $$

$$ (n-2)!(n-1)(n) = n! $$

$$ n! = n! $$

I did this on lunch break one day over the summer. I'm in high school, so my math skills are very subpar on this forum, but I was hoping some people might discuss it and/or answer my aforementioned questions. I didn't see anything about it on here or Google, for that matter. If you found this banal or rudimentary, just let me know and I'll refrain from posting until I come up with something more interesting. Regardless, I hope you found it worth your time.

Comment: These are called [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

I assume, then, that this is a common proof?

Comment: Here's another one: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^3 = {n \choose 2}^2$. Can you prove it?

Comment: I just did it on pencil and paper. It was identical, only I had two of everything.

Considering I'm new to $ LaTeX $ , I don't feel like showing the work on here, haha. Thanks for the example, though!

Comment: I did do some proofs with higher trial successes. I stopped at n choose 7 because I was multiplying 4 summations on one side and had a fraction with two sets of product notation in the numerator and three in the denominator on the other side.

Speaking of which, what do you call multiplying a series of integers with $ \prod $ ? I would think production, but I'm pretty sure it's something else.

Comment: The sums of consecutive integer powers gets complicated quickly (take a look at [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhabers_formula) to see what I mean). Far more approachable are sums of the form $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i-1)\cdots (i-k+1)$---see what you can make of those!

Comment: Sure thing!

Yeah, in my comment to the only reply on this thread, I talked about something similar where you put n choose 3, n choose 4, etc. in terms of summations.

But yeah, I'll definitely mess around with the summation you just posted.

Comment: Congratulations! You have rediscovered the case $r=1$ of the "hockey stick " formula: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity

Comment: That's a fascinating page. When I used to solve combinatorics problems by writing out possibilities, I used the hockey-stick method (?) to fund sums of sums of sums...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I was wondering if the following is a well known identity*

Not only is it well-known, but it's part of a much larger group. In general, we have

> $$\sum_{k=0}^nk~(k+1)~\cdots~(k+p)~=~(p+1)!~{n+p+1\choose n-1}~=~(p+1)!~{n+p+1\choose p+2}$$

The whole idea is to rewrite the summand as $(p+1)!~\displaystyle{p+k\choose p+1}.~$ See also [Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).

Answer (score 1):

That is an identity. Notice that $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)!$, so that the $(n-2)!$ cancel out, so you can shorten your proof!

Another way of seeing the same thing is that, if you need to choose 2 elements from a total of n, you can do it in:

- $n \choose 2$ ways (by definition)
- In the following way:

  1. Take the first 2 elements. You can do that in 1 way.
  2. Take the first 3 elements. The ways in which you can do that that don't involve the 3rd element are already counted, so you only count the ways of taking two elements out of 3 taking the 3rd number. Because there are 2 other numbers, you can either take 1 or 2. You can do this in 2 ways.
  3. Repeat this over and over until you get to taking n elements. You take the last one and you're left with n-1 choices.
  4. You add all the numbers that you got, which is just $1+2+\cdots+(n-1)$, the summation you wrote.

Because we have counted the same in two different ways, the two expressions are the same. This is called [double counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) and is an important tool in combinatorics. We can say, then, that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i = {n \choose 2}$.

Comment: I saw that (and personally thought it was the coolest part, haha). My last step was supposed to show that $ (n-2)!(n-1)n = n! $ , hence $ n! = n! $

Yeah, the way I had noticed the identity was that I was writing down combinations of 2 with 6 possible values and noticed the stairstep you mentioned (5 possibilities involving 1, 4 involving 2, 3 involving 3, etc.)that is indicative of summation. It wasn't until I began looking at probability for my AP Stat class that I realized binomial coefficients were the standard method for solving similar problems.